# How to disable OpenSSL version verification

Tags: python, ssl, docker, pyopenssl, sslv3

I'm using [docker-py](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/) and [dockerpty](https://github.com/d11wtq/dockerpty) to connect and execute commands in a container in `ucp`. Everything works correctly, except when I try to hijack the pseudo-terminal allocated in the container:

```
import docker
import dockerpty
import requests

client = docker.Client()
container = client.create_container(
     image='busybox:latest',
     stdin_open=True,
     tty=True,
     command='/bin/sh',
)

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
command = "/bin/bash"
dockerpty.exec_command(client, container, command)
```

However, when I execute the command, I am able to connect with the remote terminal, but as I type in the terminal I get:

```
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-x86_64/egg/dockerpty/__init__.py", line 44, in exec_command

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-x86_64/egg/dockerpty/pty.py", line 334, in start

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-x86_64/egg/dockerpty/pty.py", line 373, in _hijack_tty

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-x86_64/egg/dockerpty/io.py", line 367, in flush

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-x86_64/egg/dockerpty/io.py", line 120, in read

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 194, in recv
    data = self.connection.recv(*args, **kwargs)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1320, in recv

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1187, in _raise_ssl_error

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 48, in exception_from_error_queue
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'tlsv1 alert protocol version')]
```

My `openssl` version is:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
```

while the container has:

```
# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
```

Well, both are above `1.0.1`. All of I need is to disable the version verification. With the `requests` library I could just to do:

```
import requests
response = requests.get(<https url>, verify=False)
```

My `Python` version is `2.7.12` and `SSL`:

```
>>> import ssl
>>> print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
```

is also up to date. The container has `Python 2.7.9` and `SSL`:

```
>>> import ssl
>>> print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
```

I am about to create a fork from `dockerpty` and add the changes myself, unless someone has a better suggestion. What could I do to fix this issue?